# Enumerating encircled points

Tags: co.combinatorics

I would like a compact notation for diagrams with n dots and possible circles encircling the dots in all possible ways, but the order of the dots does not matter, we can move them around.
I'm attaching a sample enumeration, but It's ambiguous if we extend it.
Any ideas?[image]

In the 2nd option, the points lie on a sphere so an "infinity" move is allowed, where we push a circle around the other dots.

[image]

Comment: If the problem is to find a canonical representation, what about deriving a rule for [canonization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization)?

Comment: In the first option you have a rooted tree (where the root is "everything"). It can be represented as a balanced string of parentheses and other ways and put into canonical form by a sorting process.  It isn't clear exactly what your aim is.

Comment: My aim is like LeechLattice said, to have a canonical representation. So I could describe such a diagram with a word or a system of generators instead of pictures. So when I do computations involving such diagrams I can do it algebraically.